# How I can change the below function to update the parent also?

Tags: php, logic

The below function updates the order of all steps based on     $newStepOrder = [1613 => 3]; value provided now I want to update the parent value of all steps also. How I can do this?

```
function updateOrderAndParent()
{
    $existingStepsOrder = [
        1612 => [
                    'order' => 1,
                    'parent' => null,
                    'id' => 1612,
                ],
                1613 => [
                    'order' => 2,
                    'parent' => 1612,
                    'id' => 1613,
                ],
                1614 => [
                    'order' => 3,
                    'parent' => 1613,
                    'id' => 1614,
                ],
                ];
    $newStepOrder = [1613 => 3];
    // For each ID in the new order array (sorted by order value)
    foreach ($newStepOrder as $id => $newOrder) {
        // Get the current order of this ID in $existingStepsOrder
        $currentOrder = $existingStepsOrder[$id]['order'];

        // If the current order is less than the new order,
        // shift all values between current and new order down by one
        if ($currentOrder < $newOrder) {
            for ($i = $currentOrder; $i < $newOrder; ++$i) {
                $orders = array_column($existingStepsOrder, 'order', 'id');
                $currentId = array_search($i + 1, $orders);
                --$existingStepsOrder[$currentId]['order'];
            }
        }

        // If the current order is greater than the new order,
        // shift all values between current and new order up by one
        if ($currentOrder > $newOrder) {
            for ($i = $currentOrder; $i > $newOrder; --$i) {
                $orders = array_column($existingStepsOrder, 'order', 'id');
                $currentId = array_search($i - 1, $orders);
                ++$existingStepsOrder[$currentId]['order'];
            }
        }

        // Update the order in $existingStepsOrder with the new order
        $existingStepsOrder[$id]['order'] = $newOrder;
    }

    return $existingStepsOrder;
}
```

The final output should be based on the value in      $newStepOrder. Based on current value it should below array.

```
[ 
1612 => [ 'order' => 1, 'parent' => null, 'id' => 1612, ], 
1613 => [ 'order' => 3, 'parent' => 1614, 'id' => 1613, ],
1614 => [ 'order' => 2, 'parent' => 1612, 'id' => 1614, ]
];
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `1614 => [ 'order' => 2, 'parent' => 1612, 'id' => 1614, ]` in the final output with `'parent' => 1612` instead of `'parent' => 1613`?

Comment: @hedfol Correct updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once reordering is done (after the main loop):

1. Create an array where the step `id` can be accessed by `order` value.
2. Sort this array by keys (ascending order values).
3. For each step item check if there is a previous order value:

   - if found set the item `parent` to `id` associated with that previous value;
   - otherwise set the item `parent` to `null`.

```php
// Create the order => id array sorted by order
$idsByOrder = array_column($existingStepsOrder, 'id', 'order');
ksort($idsByOrder);
// Create an array of order values that can easily be accessed by indexes
$orderValues = array_keys($idsByOrder);
// Update the 'parent' column values in $existingStepsOrder items
foreach ($existingStepsOrder as $currentId => &$currentItem) {
    $parentId = null;
    // If there is a previous order value
    $orderInd = array_search($currentItem['order'], $orderValues);
    if ($orderInd > 0) {
        $prevOrder = $orderValues[$orderInd - 1];
        // Get the item id associated with the previous order value
        $parentId = $idsByOrder[$prevOrder];
    }
    $currentItem['parent'] = $parentId;
}
```

Complete code:

```php
function updateOrderAndParent()
{
    $existingStepsOrder = [
        1612 => [
                    'order' => 1,
                    'parent' => null,
                    'id' => 1612,
                ],
                1613 => [
                    'order' => 2,
                    'parent' => 1612,
                    'id' => 1613,
                ],
                1614 => [
                    'order' => 3,
                    'parent' => 1613,
                    'id' => 1614,
                ],
                ];
    $newStepOrder = [1613 => 3];
    // For each ID in the new order array (sorted by order value)
    foreach ($newStepOrder as $id => $newOrder) {
        // Get the current order of this ID in $existingStepsOrder
        $currentOrder = $existingStepsOrder[$id]['order'];

        // If the current order is less than the new order,
        // shift all values between current and new order down by one
        if ($currentOrder < $newOrder) {
            for ($i = $currentOrder; $i < $newOrder; ++$i) {
                $orders = array_column($existingStepsOrder, 'order', 'id');
                $currentId = array_search($i + 1, $orders);
                --$existingStepsOrder[$currentId]['order'];
            }
        }

        // If the current order is greater than the new order,
        // shift all values between current and new order up by one
        if ($currentOrder > $newOrder) {
            for ($i = $currentOrder; $i > $newOrder; --$i) {
                $orders = array_column($existingStepsOrder, 'order', 'id');
                $currentId = array_search($i - 1, $orders);
                ++$existingStepsOrder[$currentId]['order'];
            }
        }

        // Update the order in $existingStepsOrder with the new order
        $existingStepsOrder[$id]['order'] = $newOrder;
    }
    
    // Create the order => id array sorted by order
    $idsByOrder = array_column($existingStepsOrder, 'id', 'order');
    ksort($idsByOrder);
    // Create an array of order values that can easily be accessed by indexes
    $orderValues = array_keys($idsByOrder);
    // Update the 'parent' column values in $existingStepsOrder items
    foreach ($existingStepsOrder as $currentId => &$currentItem) {
        $parentId = null;
        // If there is a previous order value
        $orderInd = array_search($currentItem['order'], $orderValues);
        if ($orderInd > 0) {
            $prevOrder = $orderValues[$orderInd - 1];
            // Get the item id associated with the previous order value
            $parentId = $idsByOrder[$prevOrder];
        }
        $currentItem['parent'] = $parentId;
    }

    return $existingStepsOrder;
}
```